# Minifying issue in ASP.NET Core application

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, bundling-and-minification, asp.net-core-1.1

In asp.net core application I have `bundleconfig.json` file like below

```
[
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/css/site.min.css",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/css/site.css"
    ]
  },
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/site.min.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/js/site.js"
    ],
    "minify": {
      "enabled": true,
      "renameLocals": true
    }
  },
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/home.min.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/js/home.js"
    ],
    "minify": {
      "enabled": true,
      "renameLocals": true
    }
  },      
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/util.min.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/js/util.js"
    ],
    "minify": {
      "enabled": true,
      "renameLocals": true
    }
  },
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/profile.min.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/js/profile.js"
    ],
    "minify": {
      "enabled": true,
      "renameLocals": true
    }
  }, 
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/documentdetailmodule.min.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/js/documentdetailmodule.js"
    ],
    "minify": {
      "enabled": true,
      "renameLocals": true
    }
  },
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/css/navbar.min.css",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/css/navbar.css"
    ]
  }
]
```

when I publish the application all the files get minified except `documentdetailmodule.js`. The path and name are correct. After publishing i checked `...\Release\PublishOutput\wwwroot\js` folder and i noticed `documentdetailmodule.js` file is there however `documentdetailmodule.min.js` is not there.

How do check if there are any errors during minification ( i don't see it in output window)

I am using VS 2017

**Update 1**
Note that `documentdetailmodule.js` file is newly added to the solution. and then updated `bundleconfig.js` accordingly

**Update 2**
So after further review, it turned out visual studio actually not minifying any file ( .js or .css). The reason I see a minified version of other files because those files already have their minified version under `wwwroot/js` folder and publishing action just copies those files.

Typically VS 2017 creates a minified version as soon as you save the file. I am not sure what has changed in Visual Studio that causing not to minify file.

Comment: is this resolve? I am using BundlerMinifier.Core in Core 2.1 and it's working fine.

Comment: I had to install `Bundler & Minifier` VS extension which creates a minified version as soon as you save the file and publishing action just copies those files. https://github.com/madskristensen/BundlerMinifier

Comment: Thanks for the info I just installed "Bundler & Minifier 2022"